# How to duplicate or repeat the partial view using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My requirement is like I need to display the partial view in dynamic div based on the user presses the Add another button. I tried the below code but I can't achieve it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 0;
            $("#chkAccecpt, #btnAccept").click(function () {
        i++;
        var divElement = "<br /><div id='container"+i+"'"+"> </div>";
                 $("#frmAccept").append(divElement);
                 $("#container1").load('@Url.Content("../../Views/Shared/UserInfoPartialView.cshtml")');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainContent">
    <form id="frmAccept" method="post" action="#">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkAccecpt" value="1" /> AddAnother
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btnAccept" value="Add Another" />
        <br />
        <div id="userDetailsInfoContainer" class="Container">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/UserInfoPartialView.cshtml")
        </div>
    // Here I need the dynamic container1 div  with that partial view controls also
     </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider fetching the partial view using Ajax

```
$.get("/urlToPartialViewAction",function(data){
   $("#container1").html(data);
});
```

This will put in the view for you and insert it into a container of your choosing.
Just make sure the action returns a PartialView

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling from server
just clone container

```
$('#container').clone().attr("id","container1").appendTo('#frmAccept');
```

and you can't access view directly from browser , you have to add action for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using JQuery's Ajax method. It also allows for parameter to be send to the action.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("YourActionName", "YourControllerName")",
        //data: {param1: value1, param2: value2} //add your parameters here
        success: function (data) {$("#container1").html(data)},
        error: $("#container1").html("")
    )}
```